# IntegrityError at /update_order/ duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_order_pkey".DETAIL: Key (id)=(54) already exists

Tags: python, django

I am getting the above error . This is my updateorder view:

```
def updateorder(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    orderid = data['orderid']
    status = data['status']
    order, created=Order.objects.update_or_create(id=orderid, status=status)
    return JsonResponse('Status was updated',safe=False)
```

and this is my js:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-status')

for (i=0;i<updateBtns.length;i++){
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var orderid=this.dataset.orderid
    var updatestatus = document.getElementById(orderid);
    var status = updatestatus.options[updatestatus.selectedIndex].value;
    updateOrderStatus(orderid,status)
})
}
function updateOrderStatus(orderid,status){
    console.log('User is logged In , sending data....')
    var url = "/update_order/"
    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'orderid':orderid,'status':status})
    })
    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) =>{
        console.log('data:',data)
        location.reload()
    })
}
```

What I am wanting to do is that I have a admin page for my website where i see all orders and I am wanting to from that page change the status of the order.
This is my selectbox for reference:

```
<select
        name="dstatus" id="{{ord.id}}" class="updatestatus">
            <option value="Preparing" id="Preparing" >Processing</option>
            <option value="Out For Delivery" id="Out For Delivery">Out For Delivery</option>
            <option value="Delivered" id="Delivered">Delivered</option>
            <option value="Cancelled" id="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        </select>
        <button data-orderid={{ord.id}} class="btnabc btnabc-outline-cottgin update-status">update</button>
```

and this is my order mode:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    status = ( 
    ("Preparing", "Preparing"), 
    ("Delivered", "Delivered"), 
    ("Out For Delivery", "Out For Delivery"),
    ("Cancelled","Cancelled")
    )
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True,choices=status)
```

So my aim is that whenever from my page I change the status of order It changes in my database too. But its not happening and above error is coming.Please help me on how it can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how `update_or_create` works.

This method actually takes 2 dictionaries:

```
update_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)
```

The `**kwargs` are used to look up the object, and `defaults` is what will be updated if something matched the kwargs, if not, both dictionaries will be merged to create a new object.

```
    order, created = Order.objects.update_or_create(id=orderid, status=status)
```

Here, you're looking for an order that has both `id=orderid` *and* `status=status`. Since you can't find one (because the id exists but with another status), you try to create it. And since the id is unique, it fails.

What you want to do instead is:

```
    order, created = Order.objects.update_or_create(
        id=orderid,
        defaults=dict(status=status),
    )
```